# Call textFieldDidEndEditing of UITextField when press UIButton

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

Is there anyway to call **textFieldDidEndEditing** of UITextField when pressed UIButton?

Current process is **function** in textFieldDidEndEditing can work when user press "**Return**" or "**Done**" button and click on UIButton. To make it clear, if **ABC function** in **textFieldDidEndEditing** to be run, user must press "**Return**" or "**Done**" button of Keyboard and then click on UIButton.

What I want is I want to run **function** in textFieldDidEndEditing can work when user press UIButton.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the button handler method, call:

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

This will force the keyboard to disappear and whatever the current text field had the focus will resign first responder and the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method will be called for it.

The above assumes the button handler is in the view controller class.

Since you are dealing with a custom cell and the button is in the custom cell, simply do:

```
[self endEditing:YES];
```

where `self` is the custom cell. This will resign any text field in the cell.

Comment: great but I'm in custom TableViewCell thus how to call [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: The button handler method is in the custom cell class? If your custom cell class has a reference (ivar) to the text field, then simply call `resignFirstResponder` on the text field. My original suggestion assumed the button handler was in a view controller and there were multiple text fields.

Comment: simple question is how can I call "textFieldDidEndEditing" of single (specific) UITextField, when I press UIButton. [self.view endEditing:YES] and resignFirstResponser do not work because I've added UITextField programmatically one by one by adding UIBUtton.

Comment: Try `[self endEditing:YES];` in the button handler. This will resign any text field in the cell.

Comment: it work now. By the way, how to make focus to new UITextField programmatically?

Comment: Call `becomeFirstResponder` on the text field.

Comment: pls check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858832/set-focus-and-show-keyboard-programmatically-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

You can use textfield `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` Notification

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
        // register for keyboard dismiss notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)  name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
 - (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     // This function will be called whenever the keyboard hides. So you can implement your textFieldDidEndEditing code here.
}
```

Also when your button is clicked just resign the textfield by

```
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Why listen for the keyboard notification? The OP wants `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to be called when the button is pressed. Simply resigning the text field is all that is need for this to happen.

Comment: Yeah you are right.. Simple making the textfield resign will call the delegate