# Set focus and show keyboard programmatically in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

Here is my coding that UITextField is programmatically created when click on UIButton. But to enhancement is I want to set focus (and show keyboard) to new UITextField when UITextField is being created.

```
UITextField * txtComp=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,y, 450, 50)];
txtComp.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleNone;
txtComp.delegate = self;
txtComp.tag=i+1;
txtComp.section=index;
txtComp.placeholder = @"New UITextField";
[txtComp becomeFirstResponder];
```

Above coding work as creating new UITextField but cannot be set focus on new UITextField at all even though **becomeFirstResponder** is set.

Comment: I have checked your code its working fine here, I think there some problems in txtcom.section=index line just remove it and check it

Comment: txtcom.section=index is for grouping thus cannot be removed. at my side, why keyboard cannot show up.

Comment: I have used your code just remove that section line so it will work perfectly after clicking on button

Comment: where did you put becomefirstresponder? after addSubview: or before addSubview:?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
```

{

```
UITextField * txtComp=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20, 450, 50)];
txtComp.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txtComp.delegate = self;


txtComp.placeholder = @"New UITextField";
[txtComp becomeFirstResponder];
[self.view addSubview:txtComp];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:txtComp];
```

}

Comment: text field show after clicking on button only. are your clicking button ?

Comment: yap, textfield is showing but cursor not focus on its box and keyboard is not showing.

Comment: make sure you have conformed to UITextFieldDelegate protocol in class